# Not sure how to convert my swift 1.2 into 2.0 or if I should

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, swift2

First off, if I write an app in swift2 and ship it to app store. Will it be available/work for people still running iOS 8 ?

Right now I have written an app using swift 1.2. But I dont know how I should convert it into swift 2. Should i **first** update my podfile to use pods with swift 2.0 then run pod install, and after that I run the code migrator in xcode in order to upgrade my own code?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the latest version of Swift, and it will build and run on any version of iOS starting with iOS7. You certainly would want to migrate to Swift 2 because it's very much improved.

Cocoa pods is a separate issue, but you should use the latest version that works with the latest version of Swift.

Set the Deployment Target to the lowest version of the OS you wish to support, and Xcode will present an error if you try to use something (e.g.: an API call) that's not supported.

[image]

Comment: Cheers, but should I update me pods and run pod install *before* I run the swift migrator?

Comment: I'm not that familiar with pods, so can't tell you for sure. One strategy would be to make a copy of your project and/or pods configuration, so you can easily start over if something goes wrong.